# Change button color based on input value increment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below example I want to change the minus button background color when input value > 1. At the same time when input value = 0 it should be a default background color.

Comment for further clarification.

Script I have tried:

```
$('.quantity-plus').click(function() {
    if($(".input-number").val() > 0){           
            //alert();
        $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#f00');
    }
    else {
        $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#999');
    }               
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.quantity-plus').click(function (e) {   
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('.quantity-minus').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
    e.preventDefault();
  });  
});
```

```css
.quantity-minus {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.quantity-plus {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group qty-addon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-minus">
        minus
    </a>
    <input type="text" id="" name="" class="input-number" value="0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-plus" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        plus
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is working for me. What is the issue you run into?

Comment: @EternalHour Its not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset background color when you click on the `minus` button, at present you're only changing color in `plus` button click only,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('.quantity-plus').click(function (e) {   
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('.quantity-minus').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 1){
      $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
       $(this).next().val(0);
       $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#999');
    }
  });
});

$('.quantity-plus').click(function() {
    if($(".input-number").val() > 0){           
            //alert();
        $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#f00');
    }
    else {
        $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#999');
    }               
});
```

```css
.quantity-minus {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.quantity-plus {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group qty-addon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-minus">
        minus
    </a>
    <input type="text" id="" name="" class="input-number" value="0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-plus" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        plus
    </a>
</div>
```

---

Another way is you can fire onchange on input on each click on any of button, then based on value you can change the color of buttons.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.quantity-plus').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#input').change()
  });
  $('.quantity-minus').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 1) {
      $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $(this).next().val(0);
    }
    $('#input').change()
  });
});

function handle() {
  if ($(".input-number").val() > 0) {
    //alert();
    $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#f00');
  } else {
    $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#999');
  }
}
```

```css
.quantity-minus {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.quantity-plus {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group qty-addon">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-minus">
        minus
    </a>
  <input type="text" id="input" name="" class="input-number" value="0" onchange="handle()">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-plus" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        plus
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question again, I think I get it. If the input is above 0, you want the anchor red. Otherwise, default back to gray.

You can accomplish this by turning your example script into a function and adding it to both the plus and minus events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function color() {
    if ($(".input-number").val() > 0) {
      $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#f00');
    } else {
      $('.quantity-minus').css('background', '#999');
    }
  }
  $('.quantity-plus').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
    color();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('.quantity-minus').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
    color();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.quantity-minus {
  background: #999;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.quantity-plus {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group qty-addon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-minus">
        minus
    </a>
    <input type="text" id="" name="" class="input-number" value="0">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-plus" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        plus
    </a>
</div>
```